# How do I exclude Windows during back up?

Tags: windows, backup

I am backing up Ubuntu and went to check out how it was going and noticed it was backing up my Windows too. How do I exclude Windows during backup? It says `/host`, so would I just do `--exclude=/host`?

**EDIT:**
I'm backing up everything in terminal. I don't have a `/media/windows` folder.
`/host` seems to contain all my windows documents and everything.

Comment: What backup tool are you using?  Also, where is your windows mounted on your system (usually /media/windows, I think)?

Answer (score 4):

Since you don't specify how you are backing up, it is hard to say, but assuming you are using tar, then yes, just add --exclude=/host, or better yet, use --one-file-system to prevent it from recursing into other mount points.